# WCF: transform programmatic configuration into app.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, netnamedpipebinding

I have the following working programmatic configuration (server-side)

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
                typeof(RequestHandler),
                new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") }))
        {
            NetNamedPipeBinding tBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();


            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(RequestInterface),
                tBinding, "Request");

            host.Open();
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
```

trying to turn this into code for `app.config`:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             transactionFlow="false"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxBufferSize="65536"
             maxConnections="10"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      </security>
    </binding>

  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="ServerApp.RequestHandler">
    <host>
      <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/" />
    </host>
      <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Request/"
              binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
              contract="AppLib.RequestInterface" />
  </service>
</services>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work - i.e. clients can not connect to this.

Do I have something wrong in my app.config code? 
Or do I have to something programmatically to tell .NET to use the configuration from app.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, aside from properly assigning the type/name in the config based on the service type ... which it looks like you've done correctly, you shouldn't have to do anything else to point to the configuration.

I didn't parse through the config, but honestly, you should probably use the [Configuration Editor Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) to set up your service. It's probably the smallest little error, or mistype, or missed setting that's causing your service not to work. I've often said that XML may be human readable, but it's rarely human editable ... and IMO WCF configuration falls into that camp :-)

Comment: seems like this tool is somewhat out of date. I can't open .NET 4.0 assemblies (it is telling me that the assembly is targeted towards a more recent version of .NET than the tool supports). I was trying to add a new service

Comment: it's in there somewhere ... you're probably looking at the wrong path for an older version of the framework. Alternatively, you should be able to access it via the visual studio "Tools > WCF Service Configuration Editor" menu item

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a mex endpoint of metadatexchange may resolve this, not sure but try it once.
or its better you on the trace for service where you can find out exact problem.